# Excel: error 1004 when trying range.conditionalformat(1).delete?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following code, I recently discovered that I get runtime error 1004- user defined or object defined error if I have conditional formatting that doesn't match the range exactly.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (ws.Name = "Instructions (protected)" Or ws.Name = "ReplacementMacro (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Line Pay Finder (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Line Inserter (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Symbol Inserter (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Configuration Data (protected)") And ws.ProtectContents = False Then
        ws.Activate

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Range("A1:GJH5000")

        myRange.FormatConditions(1).Delete
    End If
Next ws
```

before the above code is run the following is run to create a conditional format and set it's priority to 1.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If Not (ws.Name = "Instructions (protected)" Or ws.Name = "ReplacementMacro (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Line Pay Finder (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Line Inserter (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Symbol Inserter (protected)" Or ws.Name = "Configuration Data (protected)") And ws.ProtectContents = False Then
    ws.Activate

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A1:GJH5000")

    Range("A1").Activate
    myRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(viewBoxEnabled=TRUE, OR(CELL(""col"")- viewBoxLeft >CELL(""col"",A1), CELL(""col"")+ viewBoxRight<CELL(""col"",A1), CELL(""row"")- viewBoxAbove >CELL(""row"",A1), CELL(""row"")+ viewBoxBelow <CELL(""row"",A1)))"
    myRange.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority

    With myRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    myRange.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End If
```

Next ws

If I create an additional conditional format after running the code that creates a conditional format through vba it works fine , but if I created any before running it and the range isn't A1:GJH5000 then I get error 1004. It seems to be an issue with the index of my vba created formatting changing so that it isn't 1. My understanding was that `Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority` should be setting the newly created condition to index 1 only, however it seems to be setting them all instead. The odd thing though is that if I have my vba created conditional format and another user defined one that has the exact same range then the delete works as intended so that makes me think the priority is set correctly, so what could be causing the user defined error and is there a work around?

[Example Workbook](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/4f3da8ed-251e-462a-86e1-28b4dd7762e4/kkBph5ABl6gJ-DLudV_HpA2)

Comment: Why aren't you using `myRange.FormatConditions.Add` instead of applying to the whole sheet and then modifying to `myRange`?

Comment: I had started this code a while ago before learning the difference between selection and range, I plan on changing it to the way you mentioned but left it as is for now to avoid adding any extra mistakes. (granted its a pretty straightforward change, I'll update if I have time before work)

Comment: I updated it to the new code using myRange for everything instead of Selection but that had no affect on the error I'm getting. Also since changing this I have noticed that the FormatConditions(1).Interior section won't change it for my VBA created conditional formatting but changes it for any other conditional formatting already on the sheet, I assume again that this is an issue with the index somehow.

Comment: Can you post a workbook somewhere that demonstrates the issue so we don't have to try and repro it ourselves?

Comment: added it to the bottom of my main post. clicking the left button will create my conditional format, then clicking the right will successfully delete it from sheet 1, however it will result in an error on sheet 2 due to it already having conditional formats on it.

Comment: I don't get an error with that workbook. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2007 and 2010, I use 2010 at home and 2007 at work and it happens on both. although I haven't tested the updated code (using myRange instead of selection) using excel 2007 yet. If you click the left button it creates a conditional format on all sheets and then clicking the right successfully deletes it on each sheet for you? (note- it needs to work in 2007 as this is intended for work)

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me on 2010. I'd suspect the issue is with 2007 which was frankly buggy as hell.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm currently testing it on 2010. damn excel can be frustrating sometimes. Maybe something is screwed up in my excel settings? or an alternative method of deleting just the one conditional format that might also work in 2007? (though again it works in neither for me)

Comment: Which build of 2010?

Comment: Version 14.0.4734.1000, it looks like there's newer builds, though that won't help with the 2007 version sadly.

Comment: Yep, my build is newer than that, which may explain it. Unfortunately I can't suggest a solution to something I can't reproduce - especially if it's a bug since the code clearly *should* work.

Comment: well at least now I know it's not a problem with my code. hopefully someone can suggest an alternative that might work in 2007 but I doubt it.